# Asp.net website Accept Login & Password from database and check if it exists go on new asp website

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to accept the id and password from username and check it with the database and if it exists i would like it to go ahead and sign-in to new asp website page don't know how to go on new Asp.net page too.

```
protected void Submit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection(@"Connection String");
    SqlCommand o = new SqlCommand("Select * from Log where Username=" + TextBox3.Text + "And Password=" + TextBox5.Text + ";", a);
    a.Open();
    SqlDataReader r = o.ExecuteReader(); //This keep showing error god knows why.
    if (TextBox3.Text == (string)r[1])
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "RETRY";
    }
a.close();
}
```

Comment: you have to use sqldataadapter for this

Comment: what is the error.. can you provide us with that much.? also read MSDN documentation located here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The query formed by your select statement does not get executed as it does not have single quotes around paramenters. You should look into the details of the error description and correct it. Avoid using inline queries. Use Stored Procedures if possible.

```
 using (SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection(@"Connection"))
    {
        SqlCommand o = new SqlCommand("Select * from Log where Username='" + TextBox3.Text + "' And Password='" + TextBox5.Text + "';", a);
        a.Open();
        SqlDataReader r = o.ExecuteReader(); 
        if (r.Read())
        {
            Response.Redirect("Aspxpage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            //-- show Error 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code dint work. it shows the same error as mine.Sqldatareader r=o.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Log where Username= '" + TextBox3.Text + "' and Password= '" + TextBox5.Text + "'", cn);

            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Log");

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {


                Response.Redirect("Aspxpage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('INVALID ADMIN');</script>");
            }
```

Comment: have  you head of SQL Injection..? I would recommend to the OP to use parameters

Comment: @Manraj : Use DataSet if it is really required. Data sets are heavier and can use SqlReader and Generic Collection to query instead.

Comment: @Shetty dataset will not take effect in this case because we are retreiving some values dear

Comment: In my experience dataset should be used when we have one or more table from which the data need to be fetched as separate result sets. It is a nicer way to use data readers and populate the values in to collections and return to Business Layer. (Not relevant to this scenario though)

Comment: we can use dataset for one table also. Now Dataset is preffering because it returns exact values which we want. Also from this discussion we have point that he might have connection problem

Comment: i agree we can use.for one table also. All I am saying is this is the standard way of doing this now. Using SqlReader also you can get exact value using coulmn name and need to worry about index of the table or row. Like reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Score"). I am just trying to explain based on my learning from fast few years.

Answer (score 0):

During submitting my question i have missed out a major important thing which was at SqlCommand o= new SqlCommand("select'"+textbox.text+"'"); Single quotes which i wasnt aware of it. i saw couple of videos and find out what was the issue and why to use it.

```
protected void Submit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection(@"Connection String");
SqlCommand o = new SqlCommand("Select * from Log where Username='" + TextBox3.Text + "'And Password='" + TextBox5.Text + "'", a);
a.Open();
SqlDataReader r = o.ExecuteReader();
if (r.Read())
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "RETRY";
}
    a.Close();
```

}

Comment: This is exactly the same thing i have mentioned in my answer :)

Comment: i agree but not completely in ur code this was mentioned ; and in my code it is nt there..thats creates alot of difference..even though i appreciate ur help and from ur code i got the solution. Thanks Pal